# currentView.start is null fullcalendar

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

I using Primeng's schedule component to display a calendar with scheduling functionality. But i keep getting the below error:

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'clone' of null
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'clone' of null
    at _fetchEventSource (http://localhost:8100/build/js/fullcalendar.js:10703:16)
    at fetchEventSource (http://localhost:8100/build/js/fullcalendar.js:10635:3)
    at fetchEvents (http://localhost:8100/build/js/fullcalendar.js:10629:4)
    at fetchAndRenderEvents (http://localhost:8100/build/js/fullcalendar.js:9789:3)
    at getAndRenderEvents (http://localhost:8100/build/js/fullcalendar.js:9780:4)
    at renderView (http://localhost:8100/build/js/fullcalendar.js:9671:6)
    at initialRender (http://localhost:8100/build/js/fullcalendar.js:9588:3)
    at Calendar_constructor.render (http://localhost:8100/build/js/fullcalendar.js:9552:4)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/build/js/fullcalendar.js:53:13)
    at Function.each (http://localhost:8100/build/js/jquery.min.js:2:2813)
```

On further debugging, i found that `currentView.start` is null and the same is setting to `rangeStart` which is the property that is calling clone in the `fetchEventSource`. I am using the `defaultview` month. I have ran out of ideas. Please help me out here. 
P.S i am trying this in angular 2. I am using `fullCalendar version 2.7.3`. The version of `jquery` is 3.0.0 and that of `moment.js` is 2.13.1.

The below code causes the error. It is part of the `fullCalendar.js`.

```
function _fetchEventSource(source, callback) {
        var i;
        var fetchers = FC.sourceFetchers;
        var res;

        for (i=0; i<fetchers.length; i++) {
            res = fetchers[i].call(
                t, // this, the Calendar object
                source,
                rangeStart.clone(),
                rangeEnd.clone(),
                options.timezone,
                callback
            );

            if (res === true) {
                // the fetcher is in charge. made its own async request
                return;
            }
            else if (typeof res == 'object') {
                // the fetcher returned a new source. process it
                _fetchEventSource(res, callback);
                return;
            }
        }
.....
```

Comment: What code does produce this error?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Please see the edit. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked if `rangeStart` or `rangeEnd` are `!= null` when `.clone()` is called on them?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes i have checked. They are both null. They get their value from currentView.start and currentView.end which are both null. These values are set for the viewType during instatiateView. When i checked the currentView value, the start and end fields are missing, hence null is being passed to rangeStart and rangeEnd

Comment: I guess I can't help here. I don't know PrimeNG.

Comment: I have the same issue with fullcalendar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran across this problem while I tried to include [angular-ui / fullcalender](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar). The last release (1.0.2) of this module depends on jQuery 2.x and does **not** work with jQuery 3.x. The first version of fullcalender that works with jQuery 3 is v2.8.0, according to [this](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3124).

I decided to fall back to jQuery 2.1.4 but if you need it, you can use the 
current master branch. It uses fullcalender in version 2.9.x.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If start date and end date are same, FullCalendar simply makes end date as null value. When cloning the end date, check if value is null, if so, use start date instead.

Check following link. Yes, it is an old know issue.

https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=1014